# pngquant EAGAIN error

Tags: webpack, pngquant

I use webpack as my tools. But I ran into a very strange error. I can figure no way to fix it. 
In my project, I need a lot of images, and when I use my webpack to build files, error occurs.

I think the most useful information is 'Module build failed: Error: spawn' and 'pngquant EAGAIN'.

If I reduce images I use, it works! Can anyone tell me why or just give me a solution? Thanks.

Here is one of the errors:

Comment: Here is one of my errors:   Module build failed: Error: spawn /Users/Zero/projects/livebet-client-code/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant EAGAIN
        at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)